# Organize a line of websites in different lines

Tags: regex, notepad++, regex-negation, notepad

I've a huge website list in a line, I need to organize it as list:

> blog.sucuri.net< br >www.pycnogenol.com< br>www.louisville.com
> lakecitylive.net< br >www.disneyfashionista.com

I need one list (removing the < br > tag)

blog.sucuri.net
www.pycnogenol.com
www.louisville.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple search/replace should do the job in notepad++.

Activate the regex option and use this pattern to match any `<br>` with optional spaces in tag:

```
<\s*br\s*>
```

And replace either by `\n` or `\r\n` depending on your needs.

Comment: Amazing! Thank you so much.